# Barycentric coordinates doubt?

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry, barycentric-coordinates

> Why does the proportional barycentric coordinates called equivalent and considered as same?

Comment: If you have three masses in a plane and compute the centre of mass, then if you double the original masses you get the same centre of mass.

Comment: Oh but in this case won't the length of the net vector change? Moreover that's an normalised barycentric coordinates that's the denominator contains sum of masses? My question basically says why normalising barycentric coordinates does not changes the point?

Comment: Isn't that what proportional means in this context? You haven't expressed the question particularly helpfully - perhaps you could give an example of what you are talking about? I think, if I am right about what you are asking, that if you normalise barycentric co-ordinates you are choosing a representative from amongst the equivalent ones - and doing it consistently across your space.